# Event Build pre & post to stop and restart Windows service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-services, pre-build-event

I've been experimenting with using build events to start and stop Windows service that are being built in my project.  However for the pre & post builds fail with an error level 255.  I've tried catching this with the pre-build with no luck.

Pre-build

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Debug"
(
 net stop myService
 if errorlevel 2 
    if errorlevel 255 
        :exit

   :exit
)
```

Post-build

```
if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release"
(
   copy $(TargetDir) C:\Media\Bin\$(ProjectName)
   if errorlevel 1 BuildEventFailed

   :BuildEventFailed
   mkdir C:\Media\Bin\$(ProjectName)

   copy $(TargetDir) C:\Media\Bin\$(ProjectName)
)
else if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Debug"
(
   net start myService
)
```

Answer (score 23):

The following weblog by Joel Varty has a solution which I use:
[Use Build Events to rebuild a Windows Service without having to manually stop/start it](http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2008/11/26/use-build-events-to-rebuild-a-windows-service-without-having-to-manually-stop-start-it.aspx)

The only problem is when you do a rebuild. Visual Studio cleans up the files before the pre-build event fires. This then off course fails because the service is still running. But regular builds work great. Hope this helps.

Comment: I prefer to have `stop, copy, start, exit` all in post-build since the service path probably shouldn't point directly to a /bin/Release folder. This also prevents the service from being stopped but never restarted if the build fails for other reasons.

Comment: @Dan has the right answer.  This also lets you easily switch to different build configs, branches, etc. without reinstalling/repointing the service.  From a comment in SDM's link, you can also auto-install the service so that for new developers it just works.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the opening parenthese on the first line of your pre-build code

Answer (score 1):

The conditional statement doesn't require double-qoute ("")

It should be like

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
 net stop myService
 ...
)
```

Comment: I believe it's common practice to always use quotes in case the variable is empty, otherwise you can end up with `if == Debug` instead of `if "" == "Debug"`.  However, in this case `$(ConfigurationName)` *should* always have a value.

Comment: Not sure. When I added "", it didn't work for me on visual studio

Comment: You might be right.  I've seen the practice many times in batch files and assumed that was the case.  With a quick search online I didn't really find anything definitive.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work:

*(this solution was a part of an enterprise software where some dll files are reused by another app)*

Model is a project which is referenced in Service project and it is built before Service. Which is why we write these codes in Model's Pre-Build Events:

---

Model Pre-Build Event:

```
if not exist "$(SolutionDir)UI\bin\Debug\ServiceFolder" mkdir "$(SolutionDir)UI\bin\Debug\ServiceFolder"

net start | find "[Service Name]"

if ERRORLEVEL 0 (
net stop "Service Name"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" -u "$(SolutionDir)UI\bin\Debug\ServiceFolder\Service.exe"
)

exit 0
```

- creates a directory in output folder
- finds the service by name
- stops it
- uninstalls it
- exit 0 causes the build process to continue if error occurs here

---

Service Post-Build Event:

```
xcopy /E /Y "$(ProjectDir)bin\Debug\*" "$(SolutionDir)UI\bin\Debug\ServiceFolder"
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" "$(SolutionDir)UI\bin\Debug\ServiceFolder\Service.exe"
net start "Service Name"
```

- copy everything needed for the service to a different folder
- installs service
- starts service

About permissions?

- visual studio will ask for elevated permission automatically